# How to install n on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I just installed [n](https://github.com/tj/n) on my Mac and everything is cool but is not installing on Windows. The process I did on Mac is:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 0.12.7
```

so what is the equivalent of doing that on Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** n [can be installed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n#supported-platforms) on Windows Subsystem for Linux, just follow the [basic installation procedure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n#installation):

**Previously:**
From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n):

> (Unfortunately n is not supported on Windows yet. If you're able to make it work, send in a pull request!)

So there is no equivalent of doing that on Windows short of forking the source code and figuring out how to make it work.